# Does the Cat Paws power allow doubling all power-granted movement while climbing?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Cat Paws are an item that helps you climb better, but while making a character who wants to utilize these items for various stunts and attacks I noticed that the wording on the 'double any climbing movement' phrasing was vague:

> **Cat Paws**
>   *Daily (Free Action).* Climb at normal speed and double any climbing movement granted to you by powers until the end of the encounter.

I wanted some clarity for how this power works by RAW and RAI. The ambiguity I see is whether it doubles any type of movement granted by other powers *while* climbing, or only doubles *climbing*-type movement granted by other powers. In other words:

1. Cat Paws doubles the *Movement* that is a part of a Power, but *only while you are climbing*.
2. Cat Paws doubles the *Climbing Movement* that a power has granted.

I assume 2 is correct, but I wanted to clarify this wording to make sure nothing was interpreted incorrectly and to potentially see if I need to find specific powers to reference climbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "Climbing movement" refers to movement using a Climb speed.

#### Essentially, it simply doubles how fast you climb either way.

If one has a Climb speed while the power in question is active, that Climb speed is doubled. If one does not have a Climb speed, climbing is generally performed through the use of an Athletics check, and is done at half your ground speed. Climbing in this way is done as part of a move action, so you can still do it as part of any power that grants you a move of sufficient length.

Therefore, whether doubling your actual Climb speed or no longer halving your ground speed, you're climbing at twice the rate you normally would. The exception would be if your movement is granted by a power that already allows you to climb at your full speed (e.g. the Executioner Utility 6 Ghost of the Rooftops), which would be unaffected since you're already climbing at full speed.